# SSISDB v MSDB Deployment for Execute Task

Tags: sql-server, database, deployment, ssis

I had some old SQL server 2012 solution files from my last data warehouse implementation, & decided to try and make them work in SQL 2019.  The whole deployment thing was not working, so I upgraded all of the packages & then made a new 2019 solution and started adding in all of the existing packages

The thing is I was bred on making DWs' in Cognos tools, so I was getting to grips with the MS way of doing things at the time, & package based deployment with Configurations was the original setting, I don't know whether they have imported into a package or project deployment model in the new solution, but I have deployed them to an IS Catalog SSISDB.

I never really got the whole deployment think properly in the fact that why do you create an SSISDB to deploy to (it seems from right-clicking in the solution file) but then when you place an 'Execute Package Task' in your package, you have to select the package either from a local file or from the package store on MSDB...  Why do you not execute the package from the SSISDB?  That means that now have to copy all of those packages 1 by 1 into the MSDB package store & have a maintenance plan to deploy all package modifications to SSISDB & then also remember to do the upload to MSDB too!?

Could anybody please confirm that I have this understanding correct, & why on earth would we want to do this?
Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

A lot to unpack here...

### SSISDB

The SSISDB is a bespoke database for managing Project Deployment model packages. Among the many benefits are: versioned deployments, native package execution, a unified logging approach, and a simplified and secure approach for configuration.

The SSISDB stores a project (the deployable unit has a .ispac extension). A project is the packages, project parameters, project level connection managers (if any) and a metadata file. MSDB stores packages.

The mechanism for deploying a package deployment model is the process `dtutil.exe`. The mechanism for deploying a project deployment model is the process `ISDeploymentWizard.exe` Visual Studio will offer to deploy a project deployment model to the SSISDB but under the covers, the process is going to be ISDeploymentWizard

I don't understand your deploy to msdb to run maintenance plan to deploy to SSISDB. That's not a thing I have encountered in 15 years of working with SSIS and 8 years with the Project Deployment Model. You just deploy the project to the SSISDB.

### Execute package task

The Execute Package task is a mechanism for one package to run another. In the Package Deployment model, you must specify where to find the package either through a file connection manager or a database (going by memory here). When you launch it, you can specify whether it's in process (wait for it to complete) or out of process (fire and forget).

In the Project deployment model, you have an additional option of a project reference package. When you use that, you don't specify where the package is because it's right here, in the deployable quantum of our .ispac file.

If you think about the Package Deployment model, I could have 10 packages all focused on a Sales function in a Visual Studio project. They are only "together" because I have them that way. There's no enforced/trust relationship between them once Visual Studio is closed. I could deploy 3 packages to the file system, 3 to the SSIS Package Store (also the file system but a predefined location) and 4 to the msdb. Or maybe just create a custom folder per package and deploy all to the file system. The point is, package1 cannot assume that package2 is in a relative location to it.

The Project deployment model *does* ensure that relationship exists outside of the confines of an SSIS project. This empowers you to design packages that take parameters when they run or use a shared resource, like a connection manager or a project scoped property (parameter).

You *could* have an Package Deployment model package that expected a run-time variable to be passed in to override a design-time variable but the Execute Package Task didn't allow you that level of granularity.

### But I want to execute a package that is in a different project and uses the Project deployment model

In this scenario, you're not reaching for the Execute Package Task. Instead, you're going to need an OLE/ADO/I-guess-ODBC-would-work-but-would-not-recommend Connection manager to your SSISDB and then you're going to fire off the correct TSQL statements.

1. [catalog.create_execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-stored-procedures/catalog-create-execution-ssisdb-database?view=sql-server-ver15)
2. [catalog.set_execution_parameter_value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-stored-procedures/catalog-set-execution-parameter-value-ssisdb-database?view=sql-server-ver15)
3. [catalog.start_execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-stored-procedures/catalog-start-execution-ssisdb-database?view=sql-server-ver15)

You'll likely want at least one parameter in there with a SYNCHRONIZED setting if you want to wait on the child package to run. Otherwise, you won't know if it when it finished. And maybe that's ok for your work.

Comment: that's the initial brain dump, I need to get back to work but happy to refine/augment that with more targeted explanations

Comment: Thanks billinkc for the input, a lot of it is over my head, for instance talking of parameters, I do not even know if it is a project deployment model at the moment, or does it mean if it has made it in to the SSISDB at all then it definitely is project deployment model?  does this mean I have an ispac file?

Comment: But, the 1 thing I did get from what you said is to not use the execute package task basically, use an execute sql task to connect to the SSISDB, which is exactly what I have done & sproc to execute package from there.  Works a charm with all the system logging & reporting linked in to the integration services dashboard...

Comment: If you took away advice to avoid the execute package task, that was not my intent. Apologies for my poor communication on the matter.

Comment: Would be nice to know why you think execute package task is any good therefore?  If I use execute package task then the package is not executed from the catalog, meaning that it is not tied into the integration services dashboard, which is pretty awesome scanning the reports to check all packge executions within jobstreams and identifying any problems...

Comment: It won't have its own entry in the dashboard because it's launched as a subprocess but if you dig around, I believe the details are there to be had. If the child process throws an exception, it will propagate up to the parent and abend the primary package and thus, is listed in the report.

Comment: A big definite plus for using the Execute Package Task for the pattern I use is the run-time checking of parameters. There's a clear interface between the parent and child packages and the package ensures required parameters exist before it can execute.

Comment: Hmmm  OK, food for thought, another thing to investigate one day when I get a chance, thanks for your advice.

Comment: Yes you are correct, the details are there in the dashboard, I cannot believe I did not notice this before now?!  Which means the execute package task is the better option, even because the parent package will register completed upon firing off the sql task, but then if that sproc package fails then it's a success recorded failure!  So thanks a lot for your help